# Select parent where all children have state x

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have Tables A and B in a one-to-many relationship (actually it could be many-to-many but I think that's beside the point here).

Table B has a state, say OPEN or CLOSED.

How can I select As that *only* have OPEN state on their Bs and likewise how I can select As that *don't* have only OPEN state on their Bs?

Database is PostgreSQL if that helps (functions?)

[image]

ie I need two queries;

- One that results in A2 and A3 (as they *only* have OPEN Bs)
- One that results in A1 and A4 (as they do *not* have *only* OPEN Bs, or
  in otherwords have at least 1 CLOSED B)

hmm maybe that's it, counts..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`.  For the first question:

```
select j.a_id
from jointable j join
     b
     on b.id = j.b_id
group by j.a_id
having min(b.state) = max(b.state) and
       max(b.state) = 'OPEN';
```

For the second, you just need to be sure that you have at least two values:

```
having min(b.state) <> max(b.state)
```